# Adding Dimensional Data for Membership in SSAS Cube Roles

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created a cube with 5 Dimensions. In one of the dimension an attribute contains user ID.
      Also I have created a role with full control, Traditionally we add user ID or user group in the Membership tab in Roles. But I want to add one of the attribute from a dimension as user ID in membership.
      The Role should fetch the data from that dimension attribute and use that data as user ID in role membership
      Is it possible to implement the same?
      If so kindly provide me the solution...

Thanks in advance...............

Answer (score 0):

The membership tab in the Roles definition wizard, accepts only a Domain User ID/Group, and so you cannot use a dimension attribute/member in this tab.